# ion-text-wrap not working inside ion-item and ion-row

Tags: ionic-framework, text, word-wrap, ionic5, ion-item

In my Ionic 5 app when I am using text inside `ion-item` or `ion-row` with class `ion-text-wrap`, the text is not wapprd. I am trying the following ways.

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
            {{myText}}
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item class="ion-text-wrap">
            {{myText}}
    </ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: It appears to be working. HTML won't wrap text that doesn't have any spaces or punctuation, like 132456789011..... You might consider prepping the text string for super-long non-breaking strings (like URLs)

Comment: @Kinglish, when I am using `div` instade of `ion-item` it wraps everything. My main concerns are long urls. Could you please explain what donyou mean by prepping the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just `text-wrap`, instead of  `class="ion-text-wrap"`

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label text-wrap>
            {{myText}}
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you! @Ani. This works. For `<ion-row>` I just have to put an `<ion-item>` inside first and then `<ion-label>`. For Ionic 5 the correct syntax is class="ion-text-wrap"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I would take in ionic5 with Angular: create a filter (pipe). This one will just try and find URLs and shorten the long ones but it could easily be extended to finding long words as well.

Your filter pipe (prep-text-pipe.pipe)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'prepText'
})
export class PrepTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(textInput: string): any {
        if (textInput.trim()=="") {
            return;
        }
        // this is just going to find long URLs, surround them with <a href's and shorten them
        let urlRegex =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
        return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            if (url.length > 10) {
                if (url.indexOf("://")!==-1) short_url =url.split("://")[1].substr(0,8) + "..." ;
                else short_url =url.substr(0,8) + "..." ;
                } else short_url = url;
            return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + short_url + '</a>';
        });
     }

}
```

Your component.ts

```
import { PrepTextPipe } from '../shared/pipes/prep-text-pipe.pipe';
```

Your component.html
Note that because we're returning HTML, I am using `[innerHTML]` rather than `{{}}`

```
<ion-item class="ion-text-wrap" [innerHTML]="myText | prepText">
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Including `ion-text-wrap` alone didn't work for me for long, unbroken strings. If you know your text is going to be a string like this (I was listing domains in ion-items), adding `overflow-wrap: anywhere;` did the trick and is pretty well supported (https://caniuse.com/wordwrap). Tested on Ionic 6.